get php version which codeception tests are running
I'm trying to upgrade my project's php version from php 7.4 to php 8.1,
Now I changed the php version in my composer.json to php 8.1 like that:
"require": {
    "php": "^8.1",

I made sure to install and update composer accordingly,
In order to make sure that the version has changed I wrote this test which should print out the php version:
class TestCest
{
    public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
    }

    public function _after(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
    }    
    public function testCountNonCountable(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->comment("I'am running on php ".  phpversion());
    }
}

and I'm running my test using this command:
php codecept.phar run my_path_to/TestCest.php -vvv --env dev
but to my surprise, the output of the test is:
Scenario --
I'am running on php 8.3.2
 PASSED 

I'am confused!. Does this mean that when I run my tests it is running on php 8.3.2 ?
if not then why am I getting this output
if yes then why isn't it php 8.1 as I specified in the composer.json ?
How can I change the php version for codeception tests and how can I tell that the version have actually been changed ?

Where did you configure that your tests (or the whole application) is actually run with PHP 8.1? Composer itself can't configure that

PHP can be installed in many different ways, it isn't feasible for a tool like Composer to change your system's PHP interpreter even if it wanted to.

The code
"require": {
    "php": "^8.1",
}

Has nothing to do with which PHP version you are using, it means this is the minimum version that should be used when getting other dependencies.
The actual PHP version is determined by which one you installed and in this case use in CLI.
